# How to find min and max values

Tags: php

I have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [Tarik Oil] => Array
        (
            [Eurodizel] => 5
        )

    [INA] => Array
        (
            [Eurodizel] => 10
        )

    [HIFA] => Array
        (
            [Eurodizel] => 15
        )

    [Selex] => Array
        (
            [Eurodizel] => 1.96
        )

)
```

I want to get min and max values of 'Eurodize'. 
How I can do this at easiest way in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Please try searching first. The internet is a wealth of resources. https://www.google.co.uk/#q=php+How+to+find+min+and+max+values

Comment: `echo max(array_column($myArray, 'Eurodize1'));`

Answer (score -1):

I assume, that in reality you have something like

```
Array
(
    [Tarik Oil] => Array
        (
            [Eurodizel] => 5,
            [Super] => 6,
            [LNG] => 4,
        )
...
)
```

And will want to run the same query for the other products. If this is the case, you should create an orthognal array like

```
$newarray=array(
  [Eurodizel] => array(),
  [Super] => array(),
  [LNG] => array(),
);
foreach ($yourarray as $k=>$v) {
  foreach ($v as $kk=>$vv)
    $newarry[$kk][$k]=$vv;
}
foreach ($newarray as $k=>$v)
  asort($newarry[$k]);
```

Now you can find the cheapest Eurodizel with

```
  $eurodizel=array_values($newarray['Eurodizel']);
  $cheapest=$eurodizel[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function that may help with what you're looking for:

```
<?php 
function getMax($array){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        if(!isset($max)||$value['Eurodizel']>$max){$max=$value['Eurodizel'];}
    }
    return $max;
}
?>
```